Is the center of mass always point-like?
I came across a video a few years ago (which I can't find at the moment) which mentioned that in certain theories (I think it was some version of string theory) the center of mass of certain systems was not always punctual.
I was wondering if some people had more information.

I've never heard of any such systems. The center of mass is always a point in every context I've ever read.

In any version of QM (not just string theory) the center of mass (CM) is a wave function. For instance in non-relativistic QM it is simply constructed from the multi-particle wave function $\Psi(x_1,x_2, \dots x_n)$ of the total system by:
$$
\Psi_\text{CM}(x) = \int dx_1dx_2 \dots dx_n\ \Psi(x_1,x_2, \dots x_n)
 \ \delta(x-{\small \frac1M} \Sigma_i\  m_i x_i)
$$
where $m_i$ are the masses of the particles and $M$ is the total mass.
So the reason that the CM is not a point but a wave function simply follows from the fact that we start with particles that are wave functions instead of point particles.

CM can indeed be thought of as a wave function in the sense that it is a plane wave carrying the total momentum of the system. But your equation looks rather weird. For two particles, we can write
$$
\Psi(x_1,x_2)=\exp(iP_\text{tot}x_\text{cm})\psi(x_{\text{rel}}) \ ,
$$
but switching to $x_\text{cm},x_\text{rel}$ variables and carrying out the Dirac delta integration leaves us with
$$
\Psi_\text{CM}(x)=\exp(iP_\text{tot}x)\int\mathrm{d}x_\text{rel}\psi(x_{\text{rel}}) \ ,
$$
which does not seem to have any meaning (other than it still being the original plane wave times a constant).

In other words, isn't this integral formula just an overly complicated way to say
$$
\Psi(x_1,x_2,...,x_N)=\exp(iP_\text{tot}x_\text{cm})\psi(x_{\text{rel,}1},x_{\text{rel,}2},...,x_{\text{rel,}N-1}) \ ?
$$

Wrong, your "original" two-particle expression does not need to have a plane wave as the CM factor, it can just be any $\Psi(x_1,x_2) = \psi_\text{CM}(x_\text{CM}) \ \psi_r(x_r)$.
But if your $\psi_\text{CM}$ happens to be a plane wave, then indeed the integral formula would give you that result correctly.

Could you please show me an example where $\psi_\text{CM}$ is not a plane wave? The separation of CM is associated with the translation invariance of the system (which is always a symmetry of the system in the absence of external forces); that is, you can always write
$$
\hat{H}=\frac{\hat{P}^2_\text{tot}}{2M_\text{tot}}+\hat{H}_\text{rel} \ ,
$$
which immediately leads to a plane wave. For example, how else would you separate the total wave function of a hydrogen atom into CM and relative parts?

Or do you define the CM wave function in the possible presence of external fields?

If there are external fields (e.g. your H-atom is in a "trap") then obviously $\psi_\text{CM}$ is some localized function. But even without external force fields it can still be any function that satisfies the free-space Schroedinger equation. So if we like to choose a neat one, $\psi_\text{CM}$ could be for instance a Gaussian wave packet (which would gradually spread out in free space as we know, but it would not be, and never would become, a pure plain wave).

By definition, the center of mass is a point.
What you might be thinking of is the fact that in some theories fundamental particles are not points.  In string theory, for instance, they are strings.

In classical physics, the "center of mass" is the "vector moment" associated with a mass distribution.  In a handwaving way, the first three mass moments are

the total mass, $\int\mathrm dm =m,$ a scalar
the center of mass, $\int\mathrm dm\,\vec r=m\vec r_\text{c.m.},$ a vector
the moment of inertia, $\int\mathrm dm\,(\vec r-\vec r_\text{axis})^2=I\propto m(\text{size})^2,$ a tensor

In introductory courses we tell students that the moment of inertia is just different about different axes of rotation; we wait a year or two before revealing that it's one complicated mathematical object. I have never encountered any use of a hypothetical $\int\mathrm dm\,r^3 $ or higher moment.

(I think it was some version of string theory)

The basic idea of string theory is that nothing is pointlike.
